# Compare strings in two pandas columns and write remainder in new column

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
Name    SubName
AB      ABCD
UI      10UI09
JK      89-JK-07
yhk     100yhk0A
```

I need a column added mentioning the characters in SubName which are not in Name.

```
Name    SubName    Remainder
AB      ABCD       CD
UI      10UI09     1009
JK      89-JK-07   89--07
yhk     100yhk0A   1000A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop here, you can use a regex:

```
import re
df['Remainder'] = [re.sub(f'[{"".join(set(a))}]', '', b)
                   for a,b in zip(df['Name'], df['SubName'])]
```

Alternative with `join` and `set` (could be faster in some cases):

```
df['Remainder'] = [''.join([c for c in b if c not in S])
                   if (S:=set(a)) else b
                   for a,b in zip(df['Name'], df['SubName'])
                  ]
```

output:

```
  Name   SubName Remainder
0   AB      ABCD        CD
1   UI    10UI09      1009
2   JK  89-JK-07    89--07
3  yhk  100yhk0A     1000A
```

Comment: please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/71634131/17778275

Answer (score 2):

You can also use apply to get the new columns, like this:

```
df["Remainder"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x["SubName"].replace(x["name"], "")), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
name    SubName    Remainder
AB       ABCD        CD
UI      10UI09      1009
JK     89-JK-07    89--07
yhk    100yhk0A     1000A
```

Comment: It is giving me the same SubName column.

Answer (score 1):

```
 df['Remainder'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.SubName.replace(x.Name, ''), axis = 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71634131/17778275